# Having trouble writing Apex trigger on custom object to update a field

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to find a way to have a trigger update a currency field based on a custom field lookup selection. I have two object **Billing** and **Courses**. On selection of a course name lookup field in **Courses_*c*** object, another currency field from **Courses_c** object  should automatically get populated in Billing__c.

So far I could write the following trigger on **Billing__c**  object, but unable to find the proper logic to apply.

```
 trigger BillUpdatePrice on Billing__c (before insert) {
  for (Billing__c bc : Trigger.new) 
  {
     if(bc.Actual_Price__c==null)
      {}
  }  
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which object is the parent (i.e. has the lookup field) and which is the child?

Comment: Parent is Billing__c. There is a course field in billing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re trying to capture the "on selection" event from Courses_c (when it changes), then you’ll need to have a Courses_c trigger instead of a Billing_c trigger. Then when this change happens, the Courses_c trigger will select all Billing_c records that are children of the Courses_c record(s) that fired the trigger:

```
List<Billing__c> billingRecs = [SELECT Id, … FROM Billing__c WHERE Courses__c IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
```

Then loop through the billingRecs list and apply the appropriate value from courses:

```
For(Billing__c b : billingRecs)
{
   b.Currency_Field__c = Trigger.newMap.get(b.Courses__c).Parent_Currency_Field__c;
}
Update billingRecs;
```

I haven't tested this code but I believe it's basically what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply. I tried and got this error..     "Error: Compile Error: No such column 'Course__c' on entity 'Billing__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Billing and Courses are two objects.Actual_Price is a field of billing and Course_Fee that of Courses. Do I have to change the SELECT statement?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm assuming that Billing has a lookup (or master-detail) relationship to Course and that there's a field on Billing that "points" to Course. I just called that field Course_c but replace that with the actual field name you use to reference Course. It's the Id you want in any case.